# is_page_template() not working in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I've got a script that I'd like to include in only a template file. The template file is located in a folder called templates in my child theme. I thought I could do it by including an if statement in functions.php and targeting the template file by name like so:

```
function header_anim() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'head', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/head.js' );
}

if( is_page_template( '/templates/home-template.php' )) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'header_anim' );
}
```

However, it seems as though it's not recognizing the if statement for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

How's it going? One thing I've done with my stylesheets that could possibly work with this script. Is structuring the if statement within the function that calls the wp_enqueue_script, and using the condition if not than return. For example:

```
function header_anim() {
  if( !is_page_template( '/templates/home-template.php' )){
    return;
  }
  wp_enqueue_script( 'head', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/head.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'header_anim' );
```

Let me know if that works for you....

Later,
Juice

Comment: Thanks for trying, unfortunately this didn't work, it's weird because it doesn't spit out any errors in the console. I've tried lot's of different variations of this code in functions.php but it just won't happen. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, how about this. Let's try to do the conditioning a little bit differently.... Do you have another function that is loading another script for the rest of your templates/pages? If so we can combine them into one function, and hopefully this will work...

```
function equeue_scripts_header () {
  if( is_page_template( '/templates/home-template.php' )){
      wp_enqueue_script( 'head', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/head.js' );
  }
  else {
    /*call enqueue script for that corresponds to the rest of the      site */
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'equeue_scripts_header' );
```

Hopefully I didn't just add another iteration you already tried. Let me know how this one works...